# Pass input types through get query strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, get, query-string

I am attempting to pass input types from an HTML5 form page to another HTML5 form page. I have used the GET query string. So far all the text fields' values are being passed, however, I am trying to pass the buttons', the date's, and the form's values as well.

Here is the relevant code for the genealogy.html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <TITLE>Relate</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
          vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
      }
      var firstName = getUrlVars()["myFirstName"];
      var lastName = getUrlVars()["myLastName"];
      var fFirstName = getUrlVars()["myFatherFirstName"];
      var fLastName = getUrlVars()["myFatherLastName"];
      var mFName = getUrlVars()["myMotherFirstName"];
      var mLName = getUrlVars()["myMotherLastName"];
      var birthDate = getUrlVars()["myBirthDate"];

      var birthDay = birthDate.toString();

      var fatherName = fFirstName + " " + fLastName;
      var motherName = mFName + " " + mLName;

      var submitBtn = getUrlVars()["mySubmit"];
      var deleteBtn = getUrlVars()["myUpdate"];
      var genealogyForm = getUrlVars()["genealogyForm"];


      var msg = ""; 

         var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TREE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, fathername TEXT, mothername TEXT, birthdate TEXT)');
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TREE (firstname, lastname, fathername, mothername, birthdate) VALUES ("' + firstName + '","' + lastName + '","' + fatherName + '","' + motherName + '","' + birthDay + '")');
         });

         db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM TREE', [], function (tx, results) {
               var len = results.rows.length, i;

               for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                  msg = "<tr>";
                  msg +="<td><h3>" + results.rows.item(i).firstname + " " + results.rows.item(i).lastname + "</h3></td>";
                  msg += "</tr>";
                  msg += "<tr>";
                  msg += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).fathername + "</td>";
                  msg += "<td>" + results.rows.item(i).mothername + "</td>";
                  msg += "</tr>";
                  document.querySelector('#tblGrid').innerHTML +=  msg;
               }
            }, null);
         });
      //}

      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="app">
         <img src="img/gealogy-view.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Genealogy Test" />
         <h1>RELATE</h1>  
      </div>
      <table id="tblGrid">   
    </table>  
   </body>

</html>
```

I added the index.html page's code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        -->
        <title>Relate</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function searchGenealogy() {
            if (document.forms[0].myFirstName.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your first name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myLastName.value == "") { 
            alert("Please enter your last name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myBirthDate.value == "") { 
            alert("Please enter your last name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myFatherFirstName.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your father's first name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myFatherLastName.value == "") {
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myMotherFirstName.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your mother's first name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            if (document.forms[0].myMotherLastName.value == "") { 
            alert("Please enter your mother's last name.");
            return false;
            } // end if
            return true;
            } // end function searchGenealogy
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <img src="img/gealogy-view.png" width="100px" height="100px" alt="Genealogy Test" />
            <h1>RELATE</h1>
            <form name="genealogyForm" method="get" onSubmit="return searchGenealogy();" 
            id="genealogyForm" action="genealogy.html">
            <h2>Personal Information</h2>
            <label for="myFirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myFirstName" id="myFirstName" required>
            <label for="myLastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myLastName" id="myLastName" required>
            <label for="myBirthDate">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="myBirthDate" id="myBirthDate" required>
            <h2>Parents</h2>
            <h3>Father</h3>
            <label for="myFatherFirstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myFatherFirstName" id="myFatherFirstName" required>
            <label for="myFatherLastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myFatherLastName" id="myFatherLastName" required>
            <h3>Mother</h3>
            <label for="myMotherFirstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myMotherFirstName" id="myMotherFirstName" required>
            <label for="myMotherLastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="myMotherLastName" id="myMotherLastName" required><br><br>
            <button type = "submit" value="Create" name="mySubmit" id="mySubmit">Create</button>
            <button type = "button" value="Update" name="myUpdate" id="myUpdate">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks like code from your second HTML5 page. Can you also post code from First?

Comment: Also call getUrlVars() once and store output in a variable and us that.